# Is there a similar UNetbootin utility for a Toshiba External HDD?

Tags: boot, usb-storage

Is there a similar UNetbootin utility for a Toshiba External HDD?  Or can I use a Utility using the UNetbootin app.  Thanks.

I misundertood the UNetbootin utility, I thought it was specific to "Ubutu".  I'm a novice at this stuff, sorry.  The bottonm line is that I want to boot off the Toshiba HDD rather than the computer harddrive.  Basically, I want to do a complete copy/backup of my hardrive to the Toshiba, so that I can take it with me on travel to insert it into the USB and direct the boot to the Toshiba.  In this manner, I would basically have a clone of my PC available on the road.  This concept would be no different than having a laptop with multiple removable hardrives.  Once I install the UNetbootin utilty, how would I use it to copy the correct files to allow the Toshiba to be bootable? I could probably figure it by monkeying around with it, but if you had a tutorial, that would be great.  Thanks.  By the way, my HDD is NTFS format, is that a problem? Is there an alternate utility for NTFS formats?

Comment: UNetbootin is a very generic tool that does not care at all about the manufacturer of a drive. Do you mean "utility" in terms of a diagnostic tool for Toshiba drives that can be copied with UNetbootin? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

unetbootin works well as long as your HDD is formatted using FAT32 filesystem (as opposed to ExFAT on 2TB+ external drives)

unetbootin is minimally intrusive. rhel/suse/mandriva image tools on the other hand will want to delete rest of information from the disk.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm trying it right now and apparently unetbootin just ignores USB HDDs regardless of how they are formatted/partitioned.